# MySQLi - dynamically assign row values to variables

Tags: php, mysqli

I am curious as to how one could create PHP variables and dynamically populate them with values of one particular row without having to one by one assign the values? Google doesnt return what I am looking for and instead teaches me how to insert variables into a sql query...

To give some background, I have a table with 40 columns and I do not want to 40 times assign

```
$variable1 = $row['column1']
```

but rather have for the value in column1 automatically assigned to a variable named $column1 with the respective value. Naturally this should be done for each value of that row.

How would one go about this? Is there a security concern?

Comment: Would the user who downvoted me explain why please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function:

```
extract($row);
```

So, you can use `$column1` as a variable

---

But **beware**:

1. This creates 40 variables as per your scenario
2. Creates confusion if your column name is same as any other variable name in your code

Comment: Can you share an example? I am unable to find this function on the php manual and cant seem to find any reference for this on google...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php. [I have already added hyperlink in the answer]

Comment: So the idea is to use `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` and then merely `extract($row);` ? doesnt return any values for me though...

Comment: It doesn't return any values, but you can access using `$column_name`. ***Use database column name***

Comment: But that still means that I have to manually enter all the variables and their names to which I want the extract assigned. My questions is if there is any way to automate this?

Comment: Why manual? creation automation is done by `extract` function. To be precise clear, you need 40 variable for 40 columns right?

Comment: Yes, but my understanding was that regardless of column amount it would loop through each column and create variables. Nevermind, I can tweak extract to do what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach

If the data returned from mysql is fetched as multi dimensional array then:

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        $$key = $value;
    }
}
```

If the data returned from mysql is fetched as normal array then:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;
}
```

Comment: the extraction seems alright, but how can I dynamically assign this to variables? All this does for me is to extract the column values, but not the column names and neither does it any variable statements. How would I use this?